# What's the best way to convert an integer (0-255) to an escaped byte (\x00 - \xff)?

Tags: python, hex, byte

Basically what I'm asking is, what's the most direct way to convert any integer between 0 and 255 into it's hexadecimal, escaped equivalent? One that I mean will function correctly if wrapped in a write() function (which means '\x56' writes 'V' and not literally '\x56'.

Answer (score 4):

That's what the `chr` function is for.

```
f.write(chr(0x56))
```

Speaking of hexadecimal escaped equivalents isn't really relevant in this context - every character has a hexadecimal equivalent, but in expressing a string the characters that can be expressed as a single simple character are simply output as the character.

Comment: Please read my title and question.

Comment: @Peaser I did read the question, and the answer accomplishes exactly what you asked. The `0x56` I used in my example is an integer.

Comment: @MarkRansom this will write `V`, and OP wants `\x56` literally.

Comment: Oh, actually, the other way around... Unclear.

Comment: @bereal from the question: "not literally '\x56'". There's no difference between `'V'` and `'\x56'`, they're identical and indistinguishable.

Comment: @MarkRansom there is no difference between those literals, but there is a difference between `r'V'` and `r'\x56'`, that's what I meant, and I just misread the question.